# is there a better way to retrieve this Json?

Tags: json, rx-java, android, gson

I've made this code to download this JSON:

```
 private void rxPublishProgress()
{
 final  OkHttpClient mOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

  final Request mRequest = new Request.Builder().url(AirportService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT).build();

    Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber)
        {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream;
                okhttp3.Response response = mOkHttpClient.newCall(mRequest).execute();
                if (response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                    long len = response.body().contentLength();

                    String progress = "0";
                    subscriber.onNext(progress);

                   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                    long total = 0;
                    int count;
                    String line = null;

                    final int bufferSize = 1024;
                    boolean flag = false;
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    final char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
                    final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
                    Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");

                    for(;flag ==false ;)
                    {
                        count = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                        if (count == -1)
                        {
                          progress = "100";
                          subscriber.onNext(progress);
                          flag = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            out.append(buffer, 0, count);
                            //  Log.d("out",out.toString());
                            total += count;
                            progress = String.valueOf(total * 100 / len);
                            subscriber.onNext(progress);
                        }
                    }

                    inputStream.close();

                    // try parse the string to a JSON object
                    try
                    {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(out.toString());
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Log.d("lengt",String.valueOf(jsonObject.length()));

                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted()
        {
          Log.d("Complete","complete");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(final String progress) {
           getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                 percentage.setText(progress+"%");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

and it works, but I don't know how to retrieve this JSON or to convert with GSON.

I need to retrieve the percentage of download because it's a specific request of this project, but I need also the JSONObject or the List . How could I do to have this?

Thanks

Comment: Lo0ok into Retrofit 2 - it will help you a lot, and it does support GSON conversion very easily.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos I know retrofit2, I've implemented a version easily but I need also a percentage of downloading...

Answer (score 0):

As i got you have 1 `Observable` and you need:

1) display percentage

2) do something else

So you can do like this:

```
Observable<okhttp3.Response> responseObservable = Observable.create(/*your code to return response*/)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .replay(1)
    .refCount();

responseObservable
    .map(toPercents())
    .subscribe(displayPercents());

responseObservable
    .map(toSomethingElse())
    .subscribe(displaySomethingElse());
```